# What is the wavelength at the classical turning points using WKB Approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, singularities, wavelength, semiclassical

According to what I know is that a classical turning point in Newtonian Mechanics is a point where a particle has a zero kinetic energy (Total energy is equal to potential energy) and must be instantaneously at rest. This means it stop its motion and reverse direction similar to harmonic motion oscillating back and forth between points $x=-A$ and $x=+A$.
In the equation given below doesn't the wavelength
$$ \lambda(x) = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2m(E-U(x))}} $$
tend to infinity when $E=U(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

1. The WKB approximation is valid in regions where
   $$\left| \frac{d\lambda(x)}{dx} \right|~\ll~2\pi, \tag{46.6}$$
   i.e. the WKB approximation breaks down near a turning point $x$, cf. Ref. 1. Generically, the velocity/momentum behaves as $\sim |x-x_0|^{1/2}$, so that the [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) has a singularity $\sim |x-x_0|^{-1/2}$
2. Recall that the wavefunction solution $\psi$ to the 2nd-order [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) has 2 integration constants. Typically the solutions in two semiclassical regions [satisfying (46.6)] on each side of a turning point are matched via [WKB connection formulas](https://www.google.com/search?&as_q=wkb+connection+formulas).

References:

- [LL] L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *QM,* Vol. 3, [2nd](https://archive.org/details/ost-physics-landaulifshitz-quantummechanics) & 3rd ed, 1981; $\S46$.